# Select/Insert only newly entered data from one table to another

Tags: sql, select, insert, logic

Apologies in advance for what im sure is a simple question:

I'm attempting to put together a query that will pull new information from one table to another on a nightly basis, I can't seem to iron out the logic for selecting and inserting only new data since the last insert. My current query is this:

```
insert into dbo.calculationtable (ID, Server, Datetime, UptimeStatus)
Select ID, SERVER, CheckTime, ResultType
From dbo.sample
GO
```

which along with some other logic in the rest of the query outputs the information im looking for, the problem is when it runs again it includes all of the previous data along with any new entries (therefore duplicating it). How would i get it to ignore those columns?

Comment: Seems like maybe you need to add a "DateAdded" field or something to your table.  Then you can LEFT JOIN on IDs and only pull where DateAdded is NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really dependent on your data, and what each column means.
Assuming that `dbo.sample.CheckTime` is a column that set to the current time when the record is inserted, then you could maybe do something like this:

```
insert into dbo.calculationtable (ID, Server, Datetime, UptimeStatus)
Select ID, SERVER, CheckTime, ResultType
From dbo.sample 
Where CheckTime > (Select max(DateTime) From dbo.calculationtable)
GO
```

Comment: Had a feeling it was something simple, looks like that did the trick thanks!